# GitHub Collaborators and Write Privileges

Tags: javascript, git, github, github-api, privileges

Let's pretend that we have a GitHub organization with 2 members in which one is the admin and the other a machine user. The machine user is added as a collaborator to each new repository that is created in the organization. In order to allow the machine user to push to the repositories we can use an acces token with just that scope. Now we have a problem, in fact the machine user could potentially push anything to any repository since the access token grants account-wide access. There are at least 3 potential ways that might be used to solve this problem:

- Create a new deploy key for each repository and use it to restrict write access only to whom has the key;
- Use pre-receive hooks to reject commits that are not compliant with some check;
- Create a machine user for each new repository and add it just to that precise repository as a collaborator with its push only access token.

These solutions all have drawbacks:

- Deploy keys are more unconvenient to create than access tokens because I need to create them myself instead of issuing a request to GitHub. Moreover I don't know how can I use them with JavaScript to be able to push to GitHub without the terminal and without installing Git on the local machine. There are many tutorials ([example 1](https://github-tools.github.io/github/examples/authorization), [example 2](https://gist.github.com/zhujunsan/a0becf82ade50ed06115)) about using deploy keys with the terminal and also about utilizing passwords and access tokens to authenticate JavaScript libraries to upload to GitHub, but what if you want to be able to push without the terminal and by only granting access to a single specific repository?
- Pre-receive hooks are an enterprise-only feature;
- Creating a bunch of machine users is not very efficent.

Are there other ways to solve this problem? Are there other ways to reject commits besides pre-receive hooks? Can you help me figure out how to use JavaScript to push commits to GitHub by using deploy keys ([what about this](https://github.com/aaronabramov/ssh-kit))? Is there a way to discover which access token was used to push using a webhook?